# Consume soap services using WSSE security with sign & encrypted header/body

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have this web service `wsdl` document at http://www.foistest.indianrail.gov.in/FOIS/FOISService?wsdl

How do I consume this is `C#.Net`.

I have the `UserName`, `Password`, `security certificate(.der file)`, `keystore file(.jks file)`,

I also have the `alias`, `storepassword` and `keypassword`

I want to connect to the `sayhello` method.